# Create a PL/SQL program to display the combined columns (customer name, bill id, medicine name and price)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Create a PL/SQL program  to display the combined customer name, bill id, medicine name and price used in a treatment.

In your query only display the results for medicine prices greater than R 200, and order the results by the customer surname.

**Sample Results**

```
CUSTOMER:    Henry, Jones 
BILL ID:     bil_127 
MEDICINE:    Anti-Inflammatory 
PRICE:       R 180.95 
------------------------------------------- 
CUSTOMER: Pam, Willis 
BILL ID:         bil_123 
MEDICINE    COX-2 Inhibitors 
PRICE:           R 307.09 
------------------------------------------- 
CUSTOMER: Pam, Willis 
BILL ID:          bil_126 
MEDICINE    COX-2 Inhibitors 
PRICE:           R 307.09 
-------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: Where is your code attempt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should read this.

Comment: This is the sort of output that I would normally handle in my presentation layer, e.g. PHP or a webpage.  What is your table structure?

Comment: I didn't do anything because i am completely lost, which is why I've posted this here.